# Facebook Friends List in TableView: Think need Async Programming?

Tags: facebook, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I am trying to get a friend list from Facebook, i have the call request inside the tableview cellforrowatindexpath but i also have it in a separate function too.  Thought to try both ways but i get the same result.

If i do a print from inside the completion block i do get results, however, if i try to print friendProfile outside the completion block it returns nil and therefore when i create the table cells they unwrap nil and the code fails.  I think it is because the completion block is not returning data until after i call to create the cells.  I am reading, and perhaps this has to do with Asynchronous programming?  Or needing to wait till data is returned from Facebook?  Or will the completion handler always return nil?

`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/taggable_friends", parameters: ["fields":"user_id,first_name,last_name,name,picture.type(large)"]);
    request.startWithCompletionHandler ({ (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            //print("Friends are : \(result)")
            let jsonResult = result
            self.friendsArray = jsonResult["data"] as! NSArray
            var index = 0
                for data in self.friendsArray {
                    let fn = data["first_name"]! as! String
                    let ln = data["last_name"]! as! String
                    let id = data["id"]! as! String
                    let picture = data["picture"] as! NSDictionary
                    let parsePic = picture["data"] as! NSDictionary
                    let url = parsePic["url"] as! String
                    self.friendProfile .updateValue((fn + " " + ln), forKey: id)
                    self.friendProfilePic .updateValue(url, forKey: id)
                    self.friendProfileID . updateValue(id, forKey: index)
                    index++
                }

            } else {
            print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
            }
    //if i do a print(friendprofilId) in here it works 
    })

   //but a print(friendprofilId) here returns nil
    let cellidentifier = "SettingsTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    let id = self.friendProfileID[indexPath.row]
    print(self.friendProfileID)
    if (id != nil) {
        let name = self.friendProfile[id!]
        let url = self.friendProfilePic[id!]
       // cell.imageView?.image = returnFriendProfileImage(url!)
        cell.textLabel!.text = name
    }

    return cell
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` in the place where you have it commented that it works. Also, don't retrieve your data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Just call the function you had in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous function call with return immediately, while the completion block will complete once it receives a response from the web server. In your case, you call `startWithCompletionHandler`, which returns immediately and configure your cell before the completion block receives a response from Facebook's server. It makes sense that `friendProfilId` is still `null` since you haven't received the data from Facebook.

Comment: how can i wait until Facebook returns the data before it continues to run the block of code to configure the cell?

Comment: As the answer from pbush25 mentions, you shouldn't try to get your data as you're creating the cells. Get your data, then re-create the cells using `viewDidLoad()`